# From scraping to a CSV file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I am new to python and I am trying to turn scraping data to a CSV file but without success.

Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import random
import re
from itertools import cycle

def cleanhtml(raw_html):
  cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>') #cleaning the strings from these terms
  cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', raw_html)
  return cleantext

def scrape(url, filename, number_id):
    """
    This function scrapes a web page looking for text inside its html structure and saves it in .txt file. 
    So it works only for static content, if you need text in a dynamic part of the web page (e.g. a banner) 
    look at the other file. Pay attention that the retrieved text must be filtered out 
    in order to keep only the part you need. 

    url: url to scrape
    filename: name of file where to store text
    number_id: itis appended to the filename, to distinguish different filenames
    """
    #here there is a list of possible user agents

    user_agent = random.choice(user_agent_list)
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
    page = urlopen(req).read()

    # parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable 'soup'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

    row = soup.find_all(class_="row")

    for element in row:
        viaggio = element.find_all(class_="nowrap")

        Partenza = viaggio[0]
        Ritorno = viaggio[1]
        Viaggiatori = viaggio[2]
        Costo = viaggio[3]

        Title = element.find(class_="taglist bold")
        Content = element.find("p")



        Destination = Title.text
        Review = Content.text
        Departure = Partenza.text
        Arrival = Ritorno.text
        Travellers = Viaggiatori.text
        Cost = Costo.text


        TuristiPerCasoList = [Destination, Review, Departure, Arrival, Travellers, Cost] 
        print(TuristiPerCasoList)
```

Till here, everything works. Now I have to turn it into a CSV file. 
I tried with this:

```
    import csv

    with open('turistipercaso','w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(TuristiPerCasoList)
```

but it doesn't return anything in the CSV file.
Can someone help me understanding what to do to turn into a CSV file?

Comment: Is the last print of `TuristiPerCasoList` empty?

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration, you are reassigning the `TuristiPerCasoList` value.
What you actually want is a `list` of `list` of `string`s, where the string is the value for a specific cell, the second list contains the values of a row and the first list contains all the rows.

To achieve this, you should append a list representing a row to the main list:

```
# instead of
TuristiPerCasoList = [Destination, Review, Departure, Arrival, Travellers, Cost]
# use
TuristiPerCasoList.append([Destination, Review, Departure, Arrival, Travellers, Cost])
```